# Removing multiple ranges of element from a List<Object>

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

My list of objects can have such elements
eg1:

```
[vale11, value12, value13, null, null, null, value21, value22, value23, value31, value32, value33]
```

eg2:

```
[vale11, value12, value13, null, null, null, null, null, null, value31, value32, value33]
```

eg3:

```
[vale11, value12, value13, null, null, null, value21, value22, value23, null, null, null]
```

eg4:

```
[vale11, null, value13, null, null, null, value21, value22, value23, value31, value32, null]
```

I want to remove the null values but not all (note **eg4**) and only those in a range started from certain index.
So in **eg1** would be something like:

```
list.sublist(3, 6).clear();
```

**eg2**:

```
list.sublist(3, 6).clear();
list.sublist(6, 9).clear();//it's not going to work
```

I know the starting indexes and a number of next elements (always the same)

Sometimes it would be 1 range, sometimes 3 , 5 ...
How to clear the original list with the use of a loop or streams ?

Comment: Streams are probably not appropriate if you're relying on indexes (which you are in order to know the range).

Comment: What is the problem? If the problem is that indices shift when elements are deleted, then run through your indices from highest to lowest so only indices that have already been handled shift.

Comment: Since you are not explaining when a `null` value ought to be removed and when not, the “examples” are entirely meaningless. We don’t know what should be removed, except for `eg1` and `eg2`, because you are telling us the ranges explicitly. Of course, when you tell us the ranges explicitly, we will also know them without seeing the contents of  `eg1` and `eg2`. So why aren’t you using `list.sublist(3, 9).clear();` for `eg2`? And what should be removed from `eg3` or `eg4`? We don’t know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use your technique with a little twist: order your ranges on the initial index in *descending* order. The rationale here is that as long as you go from a higher index to a lower index, and the ranges do not "cross over", the indexing is going to remain consistent.

Hence, clearing out `sublist(6, 9)` followed by `sublist(3, 6)` is going to work without a problem:

```
//  0        1       2       3     4     5     6     7     8      9       10       11
[vale11, value12, value13, null, null, null, null, null, null, value31, value32, value33]
//                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ [6, 9)
//                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ [3, 6)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use can do it with a loop:

Below method will remove the elements whose `startIndex <= index <= endIndex`

```
<T> List<T> chopList(List<T> originalList, int startIndex, int endIndex) {
    // Your code to check original list, validate startIndex, endIndex must inrange...
    return IntStream.range(0, originalList.size() - 1)
                    .filter(i -> i < startIndex || i > endIndex)
                    .mapToObj(originalList::get)
                    .collect(toList());
}
```

Comment: What’s the advantage over the OP’s solution, `list.sublist(startIndex, endIndex).clear();`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove `null` elements from a `List`, you can do it as simple as

```
list.removeIf(Objects::isNull);
```

Of course, you can restrict the operation to a certain range like

```
list.subList(start, end).removeIf(Objects::isNull);
```

If the actual task is to remove predefined ranges from a list (and the information that there might be `null` elements at these place is actually irrelevant), you can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50507998/2711488) (process the ranges in descending order), if the ranges don’t overlap.

If the ranges might overlap, you can use

```
BitSet toRemove = new BitSet(list.size());
toRemove.set(firstRangeStart, firstRangeEnd);
toRemove.set(secondRangeStart, secondRangeEnd);
// etc
for(int e = toRemove.length(), s; e > 0; e = toRemove.previousSetBit(s)+1)
    list.subList((s=toRemove.previousClearBit(e-1))+1, e).clear();
```

This will fuse adjacent and overlapping ranges before processing the resulting ranges in descending order.